# What is the time integral of angular momentum of a particle that is moving in a plane, about a fixed point in the plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics

A particle is moving in a plane. Let $L$ be angular momentum about a fixed point in plane. What is its time integral represent?

Comment: May be you must start with Kepler's Second Law of Equal Areas (constant angular momentum vector) and then proceed to constant direction angular momentum vector.

Answer (score 1):

It's the signed area that the line joining the particle and the fixed point sweeps out multiplied by the mass of the particle. The integrated infinitesimal areas are positive, negative or zero depending on the momentary motion of the particle.

(central force $\:\Longrightarrow\:$ constant angular momentum vector $\:\Longrightarrow\:$ Kepler's Second Law of Equal Areas)

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{1}^{2} \mathbf{L}\,\mathrm dt & =\int\limits_{1}^{2} \left(\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{p}\right)\mathrm dt=\int\limits_{1}^{2} \left(\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{\times}m\mathbf{v}\right)\mathrm dt=\int\limits_{1}^{2} \left(\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{\times}m\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf{r}}{\mathrm dt }\right)\,\mathrm dt =m\int\limits_{1}^{2} \mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathrm d\mathbf{r}
\nonumber\\
&=m\int\limits_{1}^{2}\mathrm d\mathbf{S}=m\, \mathbf{S}_{(1\longrightarrow 2)}
\tag{01} 
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it represents much that is useful, tbh.
If you divide it by the integration period it represents the average angular momentum of the object over that period.
The differential of L, that's different.